# implementing a double select box

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to design a form element that has two select boxes from which you can move items left and right as shown here, http://plnkr.co/edit/2HjvYVEqkslGNSsErXr2?p=preview.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="foorm" novalidate>
      <select ng-model="leftSelect" multiple>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <button ng-click="moveRight()">>></button>
      <button ng-click="moveLeft()"><<</button>
      <select ng-model="rightSelect" multiple>

      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.moveRight = function(){
    console.log($scope.leftSelect)
  };
});
```

My problem is that the second initially blank select is undefined since nothing is selected. I would like to be able to move elements from one box to the other and on form submission grab the elements from the second select whether they are selected or not.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing create the rightSelect variable in your controller and initiliazed it with an empty array.

```
$scope.rightSelect = [];
```

Then modify your function to something like :

```
$scope.moveRight = function(){
  var left = $scope.leftSelect;
  for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
    var el =  left[i];
    if($scope.rightSelect.indexOf(el) < 0) { // check if value is not already stored
      $scope.rightSelect.push(el);
    }
  }
};
```

Finally modify your template as follow :

```
<form name="foorm" novalidate>
  <select ng-model="leftSelect" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="moveRight()">>></button>
  <button ng-click="moveLeft()"><<</button>
  <select ng-model="toRemove" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="el in rightSelect" value="{{el}}">{{el}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

With those changes you will have the rightSelect array holding all the selected values. Please note that the ng-model for the second select can not be rightSelect that s why I have introduced toRemove.

Working plunker [over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2EJhZ2KHCIooKNDT2TIh?p=preview)

Comment: It's better to use  ng-options on select of toRemove model:
 
`<select ng-model="toRemove" ng-options="el for el in rightSelect" multiple></select>`

because it will not generate a blank option.